# Solve a differential equation with an integral inside?

Tags: differential-equations, integral-equations

I am trying to solve this differential equation in *Mathematica*:

> y'[t]+integral from 0 to t of y[x]dx =e^(-t) where y[0]=0.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 7):

### Method 1, using Laplace transform

```
eq = y'[t] + Integrate[y[x], {x, 0, t}] == Exp[-t];
eq = LaplaceTransform[eq, t, s];
eq /. LaplaceTransform[y[t], t, s] -> U0
sol = Solve[%, U0]
Simplify@InverseLaplaceTransform[U0 /. sol, s, t]
% /. y[0] -> 0
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Method 2, convert to second order ODE

You can, but you are missing a second initial condition. This is second order ODE actually. Assuming `y'[0]==0`

```
eq = y'[t] + Integrate[y[x], {x, 0, t}] == Exp[-t];
eq = D[eq, t];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The above is the ODE you want to solve.

```
DSolve[{eq, y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0}, y[t], t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: How can you use a laplace transform in mathematica to solve this?

Comment: @NimblePawn added Laplace method. Not sure why -Sin[t] shows up in the ODE method vs. +Sin[t] in the Laplace now. But these are two methods I know about. The correct answer with zero IC should be the ODE based one. with `-sin`.

Comment: I'm not sure why either. That is pretty strange. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @Nasser Nice answer :).The problem with the sign comes from a wrong assumption for `y'[0]` If you look at the original equation you' ll most certainly find that it should be `y'[0] == 1`